# When clicking on textbox to edit, cursor appear at left side of text

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm facing a rare problem with **TextBoxes** in windows forms.
I'm developing an application using *Visual Studio 2012* and *EntityFramework 5.0*, i have several windows intended to CRUD operations using BindingNavigators and List as DataSource.

When windows loads, datasource is associated with BindingNavigator and its shows the first item, for example, for entity People, it'll show first record retrieved from database in TextBoxes as:

[label]Id [TextBox]1234 
[label]Name [TextBox]Pepe 
[label]Surname [TextBox]... 
...

The problem is, when i want to edit name (or another field), i click in the textbox and cursor appear at left side instead of right (at end of text), and if i want to place cursor with mouse it won't move.

Solutions i found here are to programmatically set **selectedtext** and **selectedlength** attributes in order to place cursor at rigth, but i don't want to do this programmatically, i want it get done by itself.. as usual, as always!

[EDIT] Here is some code.

```
    itemsBindingSource is a BindingSource to a BindingNavigator

    private void Items_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....

        var result = (from i in Entidades.GetInstance.Items select i);
        this.itemsBindingSource.DataSource = result.ToList();

        ....


    }
```

Thanks so much for reading!

Comment: You'll have to post more details about the way you fetch and bind data. A norm Linq query is read-only.

Comment: What if you use Tab instead of clicking on it?

Comment: @KingKing if use tab all text is selected, as expected i think

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've updated my question showing how i fetch and bind data.

Comment: So this is only happening when you use a bound textbox? Can you repro it in a new project?

Comment: @CodyGray yes, thats rigth... I'll try in a new project

Comment: @CodyGray well, it worked like a charm in a new project, so I guess I'll have to start all over again. I don't know what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uff.. I found what the error was. First of all I want to thanks you all for your efforts on finding a solution for my probem.

I was usign a thirdparty control as mdiContainer called XPExplorerBar. After @CodyGray suggested me I repro in a new project, I did it and it worked (but that because I only programmed one widnow without mdiParent), then i added a windows form as mdiContainer and it worked!

Thanks!